# my app crashes when I start a new intent

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My application crashes when I start a new Intent and it doesn't show me any errors in the console.

This is how I start the intent

```
Button login_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register_request_button);
        login_button.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), RegistrationForm.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        });
```

The above code used to work fine but suddenly after I made few modifications like enabling lambda by adding the following to my `gardle`

```
jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
```

and

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

the same way they mentioned in android studio [website](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html)

I tried to take remove them and changing the lambda code to the old fashioned way and didn't resolve the error.

I have done multiple cmd+z (undo). can they be the cause of the problem?

my main question here is, what might be causing this issue?

NOTE : I did add the `RegistrationForm` in my manifest

Comment: Have you mentioned the activity `RegistrationForm` in your AndroidManifest?

Comment: Post your error log.

Comment: yes I did, and I can't see any errors in my error log

Comment: post logcat plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lambda convention for intent is correct. 
You should not use JACK for now as it now deprecated or replaced in android studio 2.4 preview

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/04/java-8-language-features-support-update.html

Or you can also Use retrolambda if you want as jack is not supported with databinding.

For your question: **my main question here is, what might be causing this issue?**

Check you logs to find why the application is crashing
as you said you have defined it in android manifest so that would not be an issue.

Check view whether is null or not (might not be refrenced properly)

I dont think there is any problem with build process as application crashes at runtime.

Do share you log in question.

Comment: I am using my android phone to test the application and I can't see any errors in my even log. do you have any idea why? thanks for your reply

Comment: That might be because of ADB try restart adb server and log will be generated

Comment: You can +1 or accept answer if that answer your question

Answer (score 0):

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,TextActivity.class));
        }
    });
```

And cheek your activity is registered in manifest

```
 <activity android:name=".TextActivity"
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),RegistrationForm.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```